# PayPal Invoicing - Template selection during API call

Tags: php, paypal, invoice

I have used the following tutorial to set up PayPal create and send invoice.

URL: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7269-PHP-Create-and-manage-invoices-Paypal-Invoicing-API.html

My client has created templates in his PayPal account and wants me to send specific templates on specific scenario's.

Example: When a user selects 'offline payment' in the site, the template created for offline payment, in PayPal must be sent.

I pitched in the option, where I can provide different 'notes' using the '`$aryCreateInvoice['invoice.note']`', but he wants to be able to edit them from PayPal and not anywhere else.

Is this possible using the invoice number or anything that I can pass to get the template Id or something ?

Please let me know if there is no solution for this so that I can strongly mention to my client that this is not possible.